# ld cannot find -lmpi when building Valgrind from source

Tags: mpi, valgrind

I'm trying to build Valgrind 3.21.0 from source, I downloaded the archive [here](https://valgrind.org/downloads/) and followed the instructions in the README :

1. Run ./configure
2. Run "make"
3. Run "make install", possibly as root if the destination permissions
   require that.

When I run the "make" command, I get this error :

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/opt/valgrind-3.21.0/memcheck'
../coregrind/link_tool_exe_linux 0x58000000 mpicc     -o memcheck-amd64-linux  -m64 -O2 -g -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wempty-body -Wformat -Wformat-signedness -Wformat-security -Wignored-qualifiers -Wmissing-parameter-type -Wlogical-op -Wenum-conversion -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wold-style-declaration -finline-functions -fno-stack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin   -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -static -nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles -u _start -Wl,--build-id=none -m64 memcheck_amd64_linux-mc_leakcheck.o memcheck_amd64_linux-mc_malloc_wrappers.o memcheck_amd64_linux-mc_main.o memcheck_amd64_linux-mc_main_asm.o memcheck_amd64_linux-mc_translate.o memcheck_amd64_linux-mc_machine.o memcheck_amd64_linux-mc_errors.o ../coregrind/libcoregrind-amd64-linux.a ../VEX/libvex-amd64-linux.a -lgcc ../coregrind/libgcc-sup-amd64-linux.a 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1133: memcheck-amd64-linux] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/opt/valgrind-3.21.0/memcheck'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1444: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/valgrind-3.21.0/memcheck'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:914: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/valgrind-3.21.0'
make: *** [Makefile:777: all] Error 2
```

It seems ld cannot find -lmpi, but I have OpenMPI 4.2.1 installed and when I run `ld -lmpi --verbose`, ld finds all files correctly.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04, and I can't use default valgrind (v3.18.1) because I get an error that I couldn't solve either when I try to use it :

```
==48326== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==48326== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==48326== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==48326== Command: ./spheres
==48326== 
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x25
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x25
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x25
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x23
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x25
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x25
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x25
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x23
==48326== Valgrind: debuginfo reader: ensure_valid failed:
==48326== Valgrind:   during call to ML_(img_get)
==48326== Valgrind:   request for range [1279783701, +4) exceeds
==48326== Valgrind:   valid image size of 113115128 for image:
==48326== Valgrind:   "/usr/local/lib/libvtkCommonCore-9.1.so.9.1.0"
==48326== 
==48326== Valgrind: debuginfo reader: Possibly corrupted debuginfo file.
==48326== Valgrind: I can't recover.  Giving up.  Sorry.
==48326==
```

A friend of mine has the same problem with Valgrind 3.18.1 but he avoided it by building Valgrind 3.21.0 from source. Thank you for reading this post, I hope I'll find a solution here.

[EDIT]
I tried to grep where -lmpi was in all valgrind files, and found in my config.log these suspicious lines :

```
configure:6817: checking for a supported CPU
configure:6844: result: ok (x86_64)
configure:6941: checking for a 64-bit only build
configure:6956: result: no
configure:6960: checking for a 32-bit only build
configure:6975: result: no
configure:6988: checking for a supported OS
configure:6996: result: ok (linux-gnu)
configure:7001: checking for the kernel version
configure:7014: result: 2.6 or later (6.2.0-26-generic)
configure:7325: checking for 32 bit build support
configure:7343: mpicc -o conftest -m32   conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so when searching for -lmpi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so when searching for -lmpi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so when searching for -lmpi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so when searching for -lmpi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc: No such file or directory
```

but at the end, the configure command doesn't complain, it exits with status 0. It's only when I run make that the problem occurs so I don't know if these lines are related to the problem. I think the ./configure is just trying to compile in 32bits and it doesn't work but this is a normal behavior.

I'm not sure what I should do now.

Comment: Does it help if you run both autogen.sh and then configure?

Comment: I tried that too, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: look into `config.log` which command triggers "skipping incompatible ..." is it because you build 32bits binaries?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I edited my post adding the previous lines of config.log . But as I mentioned I'm not sure these lines are linked to the problem.

Comment: so you are trying to build `valgrind` for **both** 32 and 64 bits, but your MPI implementation is 32 bits only (e.g. `mpicc` does not understand `-m32` and/or no 32 bits MPI library is available). if you only need a 64 bits build, then look for the corresponding `configure` option, this is likely the easiest path.

Comment: The first error is when trying to link the 64bit memcheck exe. You're also getting configure errors when it checks whether to build the 32bit secondary targets (which is the default). Try `--enable-only64bit` and/or playing with LDFLAGS so that it finds the right libmpi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The command causing trouble during `make` starts with `../coregrind/link_tool_exe_linux 0x58000000 mpicc`  where mpicc is my default C compiler. This mpicc command is a wrapper calling gcc with additional flags : `gcc -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib -lmpi`. And here is the `-lmpi` that cannot be found during the make command (while there is no problem running a simple MPI program with mpicc). As explained in @GillesGouaillardet's comment, my MPI implementation is 64 bits only and I'm trying to build valgrind for both 32 and 64 bits.

So the simple solution I found was to use gcc directly instead of mpicc :

```
export CXX=g++ && export CC=gcc
```

Then rerun `./configure`, `make` and `make install`.

As @GillesGouaillardet and @PaulFloyd suggested in their comments, another solution should be to look for the `./configure` options to build valgrind for 64 bits only (if it is the root of the problem).

Thank you all for your help.